# space in the name of sql table

Tags: excel, vba

the macro below exports data to SQL tables, when the name of the table has no space, it works perfectly, but if the name has a space, it blocks,

it blocks on the rs.Open line tableName, Cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

I tried the hooks [...] the apostrophe '...' and `...` but nothing works
   `

```
Sub Injection()


Dim Cn As ADODB.connection    
Dim ServerName As String    
Dim DatabaseName As String    
Dim tableName As String    
Dim UserID As String    
Dim Password As String    
Dim rs As ADODB.recordset    

ServerName = "vmalsdisdb"
DatabaseName = "Produits"
tableName = "PRELEVEMENT PRODUIT"
UserID = ""
Password = ""


Set rs = New ADODB.recordset


Set Cn = New ADODB.connection
Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & ServerName & ";Database=" & DatabaseName & _
";Uid=" & UserID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"


rs.Open tableName, Cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic`
```

Comment: What error are you getting? I was able to use `[]` successfully, like `tbl = "[PRELEVEMENT PRODUIT]"        rs.Open tbl, cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic`.

Comment: Maybe try different arguments in your `Open` method like `rs.Open tbl, cn, adOpenStatic`. If that works, then it's not letting you open it or lock the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

That's weird!  It works fine for me in my test scenario!

```
Sub ADOExcelSQLServer()
     '
     ' FOR THIS CODE TO WORK
     ' In VBE you need to go Tools References and check Microsoft Active X Data Objects 2.x library
     '

    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Server_Name = "EXCEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS" ' Enter your server name here
    Database_Name = "Test Method" ' Enter your database name here
    User_ID = "" ' enter your user ID here
    Password = "" ' Enter your password here
    SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM [mytable]" ' Enter your SQL here

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
    ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic
     ' Dump to spreadsheet
    For iCols = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = rs.Fields(iCols).Name
    Next
    With Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a2:z500") ' Enter your sheet name and range here
        '.ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
     '            Tidy up
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

I suppose you can try triple quotes around any 'weird' naming conventions, like spaces in names, or special characters in names.

Answer (score -1):

thank you all for your answers, the problem was not worry in space but in one of the Tables, I was able to bypass the problem by replacing the cursor type "adOpenKeyset" by "adOpenDynamic"
but his understanding the problem, may be that another user worked on the table ?!